# Is there a way to define a routes.json file when initializing a json-server in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json-server

If you want to use a routes.json file for custom json-server routing from the command line, you can do so with the --routes option like this:

```
json-server --watch db/db.json --routes db/routes.json --port 9001
```

However, I don't see a similar option anywhere if you are starting your json-server from a javascript file. I am looking for something like this:

```
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
server.use(router)

// This part is what I am looking for
const customRouter = jsonServer.customRouter('routes.json')
server.use(customRouter)

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running')
})
```

I know we can do explicit custom routing in javascript but that is verbose and I would prefer to just reference a routes.json file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One will need to use the `rewriter` api that the `json-server` provides.
Example from the [documentation](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/#rewriter-example):

```
// Add this before server.use(router)
server.use(jsonServer.rewriter({
  '/api/*': '/$1',
  '/blog/:resource/:id/show': '/:resource/:id'
}))
```